# mysql stored function simple login, extract int from set

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

this is my first mySQL stored-function 'cause i've always managed such things with php.
I want a function that checks if a user can log in my client-area.
I wrote the code above:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `A05`.`login` (user VARCHAR(64),pass VARCHAR(64)) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    declare num_rows int;
    declare id int;
    SELECT (@num_rows:=COUNT(*)),(@id:=`Credential_id`) FROM `A05`.`Credentials` where `Credential_UserName` = user;    
    if num_rows = 0 then
        -- user not present
        return (-1);
    end if;
    -- user present, checking password
    SELECT (@num_rows:=COUNT(*)),(@id:=`Credential_id`) FROM `A05`.`Credentials` where `Credential_id` = id AND `Credential_PASSWORD` = SHA1(pass); 
    if num_rows = 0 then
        -- user presente, password incorrect
        INSERT INTO  `a05`.`Events` (
            `Event_id` ,
            `Event_RegistrationDate` ,
            `Event_VariationDate` ,
            `Event_State`,
            `Event_Notes`,
            `Event_SenderId`,
            `Event_Type`
        )
        VALUES (
            NULL ,  NOW(),  NOW(), 'wp', NULL, id, 1
        );
        return (-2);
    end if;
    -- user present, password correct
    UPDATE `A05`.`Credentials` SET `Credential_LastAccess`=NOW() where `Credential_id` = id;
    INSERT INTO  `a05`.`Events` (
        `Event_id` ,
        `Event_RegistrationDate` ,
        `Event_VariationDate` ,
        `Event_State`,
        `Event_Notes`,
        `Event_SenderId`,
        `Event_Type`
    )
    VALUES (
        NULL ,  NOW(),  NOW(), 'ok', NULL, id, 0
    );
    return id;
END
```

I think that the syntax should be right except for the last statement return id cause i return a set instead of an integer.
The problem is that when i try to store this function on mysql i get this error:

```
Error 1415: Not allowed to return a result set from a function
```

Then i changed the last statement from 'return id' to 'return 0' for testing purpose but i keep getting the same error.
Probably is a newbie error cause it's the very first time for me on sql "advanced" scripting.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Use backticks around all instances of `user` in the function. It is a reserved keyword.